# Ubuntu 14.10 High DPI Intel HD Graphics Not Supported

Tags: drivers, graphics, intel-graphics

On my Lenovo t540p running Ubuntu 14.10, the animations associated with expo, window spread, minimize, and workspace switch are choppy when the resolution is set above 1920x1080. One can see a stutter in the animation.

The graphics card is `Intel 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller` and the driver is `intel  (unloaded: fbdev, vesa)` as reported using `inxi -Gs`.

Is there a way to get the graphics card working at full resolution (2880x1620)?

Comment: Can you define "terrible" in a reasonable way? I am using a a 4K (3840x2160) monitor on Intel i7 graphics at 30 fps, without any significant problems.

Comment: @dobey I've updated the question. Thats iteresting.. do you often use expo and window spread and find that the animations are at all choppy?

Comment: No, the window spread is pretty fast here. On an i7 4790S.

Comment: Hmm, I have an i7 4700MQ. Is there anything special about your xorg.conf or anything like that? What driver are you using?

Comment: No. It's the stock Intel driver included in 14.04. I don't have an xorg.conf. Does your laptop have a dual video card setup (both Intel and Nvidia available)?

Comment: No, just the integrated graphics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, Intel does not provide official drivers for Ubuntu 14.10.

They've stated that drivers for 14.10 will likely be released within their next quarterly release ([Source](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/node/375)).

You can keep an eye on their download page [here](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads). The current installer is at v1.0.6, so I'm going to guess that v1.0.7 will be the next in line.

If the performance hit is really bothering you, I'd maybe suggest downgrading to 14.04 until drivers are released and then simply upgrading from there.